# Which part of Fubini's hypothesis is violated?

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f(x, y)= (4xy−x^2−y^2)(x+y)^{−4}$ for $x$, $y$ both positive, and let $f (x, y) = 0$ elsewhere. Integration first with respect to $x$ on $(0,∞)$ then with respect to $y$ on $(0,∞)$ yields $0$. Also integration first with respect to $y$ on $(0,∞)$ then with respect to $x$ on $(0,∞)$ yields $0$. But integration first with respect to $x$ on $(0,a)$ then with respect to $y$ on $(0,a)$ yields $\frac14$ which stays $\frac14$ when $a \to ∞$. Where am I doing wrong since I thick no part of Fubini's hypothesis is violated?

Comment: Did you prove the function is absolutely integrable? This is the main hypothesis that needs to satisfy.

Comment: Your function is neither integrable nor non-negative.

Comment: @BokaPeer, the book says f must be "countably $(μ^∗×ν^∗)$-measurable" it doesn't talk about "integrable" and/or "non-negative" ; it talks about them when introducing Tolleni thm not Fubini's! What is **countably** $(μ^∗×ν^∗)$-measurable?

Comment: I do not know which books you are using. In general, Fubini requires integrability and Tonelli requires positivity. Also, I am not sure about the phrase you wrote. My guess is that the phrase you wrote means "sigma finite measure."

Comment: @BokaPeer, Bruckner's Real Analysis Chapter 6. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look, and will let you know if you don't have an answer.

Comment: @BokaPeer, consider $f=e^{-xy}-2e^{-2xy}$, it is absolutely integrable though non-positive but if you integrate with respect to first x then y also first y then x they are different (mentioned in Ex 6:2.5). So Tonelli and Fubini are not consistent? (http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Bruckner%2C%20Andrew%20M.)

Comment: @L.G. you are wrong, the function $f=e^{-xy}-2e^{-2xy}$  are not integrable (in the sense of Lebesgue) in $(0,1)\times(0,\infty)$. What you have is that in each of the iterated integrals, the integrands exists in the sense of Lebesgue. $\int_Af(x,y)\,dy\in L_1(B)$ and $\int_Af(x,y)\,dx\in L_1(A)$ does not mean that $f(x,y)\in L_1(A\times B)$ (unless $f\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather large comment so I put it in the answer section.

Fubini-Tonelli's theorem states that if $f$ is measurable in $\mathscr{M}(\mu^*\otimes\nu^*)$ and its carrier $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: f(x,y)\neq0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite (with respect to $\mu^*\otimes\nu^*$), then $f\in L_1(\mu^*\otimes \nu^*)$ iff one of the iterated integrals $\int_X\Big(\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^*(dx)$ or $\int_Y\Big(\int_X|f(x,y)|\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)$ exists and are finite. When this happens,
$$
\int_{X\times Y} f(x, y)\,\mu^*\otimes \nu^*(dx,dy)=\int_X\Big(\int_Yf(x,y)\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^*(dx)=\int_Y\Big(\int_Xf(x,y)\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)
$$
and
$$
\int_{X\times Y} |f(x, y)|\,\mu^*\otimes \nu^*(dx,dy)=\int_X\Big(\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^*(dx)=\int_Y\Big(\int_X|f(x,y)|\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)
$$

It also says that of either of the aforementioned iterated integrals of $|f|$ is infinite, then so will the other and in this case $\int_{X\times Y}|f| d(\mu^*\otimes \nu^*)=\infty$.

---

In your case, since you are dealing with Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or rather the product of one dimensional Lebesgue measure) there is no need to worry abut the $\sigma$--finiteness condition, for this property is obvious.

As Kavi Rama Murthy mentioned, the function in the OP
$$ f(x,y)=\frac{4xy-(x^2+y^2)}{(x+y)^4}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)}(x,y)$$
**is not Lebesgue integrable**. A quick way to see this is by using polar coordinates and consider the integral over a quarter of a circle $C^+_R$ centered at the origin with radius $R$. Then
$$
\int_{C^+_R}|f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy=\int_{(0,R]\times[0,\pi/2)}\frac{|1-2\sin(2\theta)|}{|\cos\theta+\sin\theta|}\frac{1}{r}\,dr\,d\theta=\infty
$$

So, for this function, knowing that the iterated integrals $\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^\infty_0f(x,y)\,dx\Big)\,dy)$ and $\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^\infty_0f(x,y)\,dy\Big)\,dx)$ exists, are finite  and are equal does not provide definite information about the integrability of $f$, for $f$ is not positive, and further inspection shows that $f$ is not integrable.

---

The OP made a comment also about the function $\phi(x,y)=e^{-xy}-2 e^{-2xy}$ where he/she states that $f$ is absolutely integrable (in $[0,1]\times(0,\infty)$ and that the interested integrals differ. I took a look at the reference he quoted, and I believe the OP misunderstood what it is written there. In fact, **$|\phi|$ is not integrable** (Lebesgue integrable)
$$
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\Big(\int^\infty_0|\phi(x,y)|\,dy\Big)\,dx&=\int^1_0\Big(\int^{x^{-1}\log 2}_0|\phi(x,y)|\,dy\Big)\,dx + \int^1_0\Big(\int^\infty_{x^{-1}\log 2}|\phi(x,y)|\,dy\Big)\,dx\\
&= I_1+I_2
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
 I_1=\int^1_0 \Big(\int^{x^{-1}\log 2}_0 2e^{-2xy}-e^{-xy}\,dy\Big)dx&=
\int^1_0\Big(\frac{1}{x}(-e^{-2xy}+ e^{-xy})|^{y=x^{-1}\log 2}_{y=0}\Big)\,dx \\
&=\int^1_0 \frac{1}{x}(e^{-\log 2}- e^{-2\log 2})\,dx=\infty
\end{align}
$$
Similar calculation for $I_2$.

Comment: About your last paragraph (before last edit), can be a function $f(x,y)$ such that the iterated integrals $\int_A\Big(\int_Bf(x,y)\,dx\Big)\,dy)=\int_B\Big(\int_Af(x,y)\,dy\Big)\,dx)$ for any measurable A,B and still $f(x,y)$ not integrable in sense of Fubini’s theorem?

Comment: As long as $f$ is not positive, yes. Your's may be an example ($f$ in the OP, if your calculations are correct).

Comment: The book hasn't stated Fubini-Tonelli's theorem clearly and what you've stated at the beginning for the theorem is Ex6:3.3 of the book. Can you please provide an easy to understand reference for a proof of your statement of the Fubini-Tonelli's theorem?

Comment: It is basically a combination of Fubini and Tonelli's/. Fubini's gives conditions for equality of iterated integrals when $f$ is integrable; Tonelli's  gives sufficient conditions for integrability in terms of equality of iterated integrals of $|f|$. Put the two togwuter and you get and if and only if statement. The version I have I learned from Klaus Bichteler's Integration theory: A functional approach. It is less than 200 pages, but not easy (nor  cheap in price) as he develops the theory of integration following Daniell's approach, as oppose to the measure theoretic approach.

Comment: @Lebesgue-Caratheodory's and DAniell-Stones's approaches though different, give the same space of inter garble functions. The advantage, in my view, is that the later approach can be used naturally to build other objects such as the Stochastic integral, as well as other functional integrals (Bochner's integral).

Comment: Excellent answer!