# Examples-Counterexamples for understanding Fubini's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Fubini's theorem in measure theory states that,

> *Statement:* Let $(X,\mathcal S,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal F,\nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces,and $\mu\times \nu$ denote the product measure on $X\times Y$.If $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb R$ is measurable and $\iint_{X\times Y} |f(x,y)|d(\mu\times \nu)<\infty$ then $\int_X(\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y))d\mu(x)=\int_Y(\int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x))d\nu(y)=\iint_{X\times Y} f(x,y)d(\mu\times \nu)$.

Now I want a better understanding of Fubini's theorem.So I want to deal with some examples-counterexamples related to this theorem.I want counterexamples for the following:

$1. $ If $\iint_{X\times Y} |f|d(\mu\times \nu)=\infty$,then the conclusion of the theorem may not be true i.e. the iterated integrals may not be equal.So,it is an essential condition.

$2.$ Even if $\iint_{X\times Y} |f|d(\mu\times \nu)=\infty$,stil it may happen that the iterated integrals are equal i.e. this is not a necessary condition.

$3.$ Can it happen that one of the iterated integrals is finite and the other is infinite?

$4.$ Even if both the iterated integrals are finite,need they be equal?

Can someone please suggest me some counterexamples?It is better if the function $f$ is defined on a subset $\mathbb R^2$ and the measure involed is the product measure $\mathcal L(\mathbb R)\times \mathcal L(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: For (1) see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3115908/148510)

Comment: That would also answer (4) as an example where iterated integrals are finite and unequal.

Comment: @RRL So the idea is to take a function which is skew-symmetric $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ .So,that the iterated integrals are negative to each other.Here they have taken $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$.

Comment: And we are integrating on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes -- that is how it works.  Also we have $|f(x,y)| = \mathcal{O}\left[(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\right]$ as $x,y \to 0$ so it is not absolutely (or Lebesgue) integrable.

Comment: You asked a related question -- same technique applies.  In fact, I can answer all of these questions, but the problem is they do not meet site quality standards.  See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510) and try to improve.

Comment: @RRL What about $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Comment: @RRL Please give me some hint,I do not understand how the same technique applies.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4126780/121671) is another example

Comment: @RRL I have found one example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812264/not-integrable-although-iterated-integrals-are-equal

Comment: @RRL But I do not understand from the link why $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$.